# Partition function of a chain, at the end of which as mass experiencing gravity

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Let us consider the following system (question 12.3 from Huang's Statistical Mechanics book)

[image]

> A chain made of $N$ segments of equal length $a$ langs from the ceiling. $\mathrm{A}$ mass $m$ is attached to the other end under gravity. Each segment can be in either of two states, up or down, as illustrated in the sketch.

I'm trying to find the partition function of this system.

**My work:**

To that end, I put my coordinate axis to L distance below the ceiling such that the height of the mass $h$ is $L_0 = a(N-N_+)$ where $N_+$ is the #segments added in the downwards direction.

Now the partition function is equal to the sum of $e^{-\beta H}$ over all the microstates of the system. Since Hamiltonian is $H = mgh$, then
$$Q_N = \sum_{\text{all possible $h$}} e^{-\frac{mgh}{k_bT}}.$$

Given that $N = N_+ + N_{-}$ and that $L = a(N_+ - N_-) = a(N-2N_+)$,
$$h=L_0 - L = aN - 2a(N-N_+) = 2a (N-N_+)$$.

This means that
$$Q_N = \sum_{N_+=0}^N e^{-\frac{mg2a (N-N_+)}{k_bT}} = e^{\frac{mga(2N)}{k_bT}} \sum_{N_+=0}^N e^{-\frac{-mg2aN_+)}{k_bT}}.$$

According to the wolframalpha, this equals to

$$Q_N = \frac{\left(-1+e^{mg2a+mg2a N}\right)}{-1+e^{mg2a}}.$$

This result is different from the one given in the book, namely
$$Q_{N}=\left(1+\mathrm{e}^{-m g a / k T}\right)^{N}.$$

**Question:**

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Addedum:**

In the solution book, the answer is given as

> Assume that a link can be up or down independently. The partition function is the product of the partition functions of the individual links. The possible energies are 0 and $m g a$. Thus $Q_{N}=[1+\exp (-\beta m g a)]^{N}$. We have ignored the fact that the energy of the $n$ th link depends on its height, and therefore on the states of the preceding links. We have also ignored is the restriction that the links cannot go above the ceiling.

But this is wrong. There is no energy associated with any link going down or up. Only the net result of all the alignment of the link, hence the total length, has an associated energy coming from the potential energy of the mass.

Comment: Note that you have forgotten the combinatorial factor $\binom{N}{N_+}$ counting all possible configurations with $N_+$ downward segments. Use the binomial theorem to evaluate the resulting sum. You'll get something much closer to what his solution.

Comment: Check also your formula for $L_0$, which is not quite correct. Check it on the picture.

Comment: @Yvan Velenik  How do you write the binomial coeffcients in MathJax?  I tried "N \chose N_+"  but the code was not recognized ....

Comment: @mikestone I used \binom{N}{N_+} ...

Comment: @Yvan Velenik  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have $N_+$ uplinks out of $N$ (so the Boltzmann factor is $\exp\{-\beta mga N_+\}$) the corresponding number of microstates is the binomial coefficient "$N$ choose $N_+$" or
$$
{N \choose N_+}=\frac{N!}{N_+! N_-!}.
$$
The partition function is therefore
$$
Z= \sum_{N_+=0}^N \frac{N!}{N_+! N_-!}\exp\{-\beta mga N_+\}= (1+\exp\{-\beta mga\})^N
$$